# How can I get the right html code to scrape with Python using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, facebook, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

for educational purpose, I would like to scrape the Facebook Ad Library using python.

For example, let say that I would like to scrape [this page](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=ALL&impression_search_field=has_impressions_lifetime&view_all_page_id=51212153078&sort_data[direction]=desc&sort_data[mode]=relevancy_monthly_grouped):

When I inspect the element I see various kinds of divs that I can use to extract information. 
But when I try to get this page html code using BeautifulSoup I get a completely different code from what I saw from inspecting the element.

[This is what I get.](https://codeshare.io/aJRmBr)

And this is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=ALL&impression_search_field=has_impressions_lifetime&view_all_page_id=51212153078&sort_data[direction]=desc&sort_data[mode]=relevancy_monthly_grouped")
c=r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Do you know how can I get access to the code that I see by inspecting the page? Thanks a lot!

P.S. As you can see I'm very new to coding, so if you have any suggestions on how to better share the code that I just linked I would be very happy to learn how to do it and edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Why would you scrape Facebook which doesn't allow scraping if it is just for educational purposes. Just use some other site that allows it

Comment: @WizKid nice point! My problem with programming is that every time I try to do a project without following a tutorial I gave up once I found the first difficulties. Because I really liked what I had in mind (scraping copy for a brand and then do semantic analysis) I didn't want to give up so early. So after your comment, my question is: I cannot scrape these kinds of pages because Facebook doesn't allow it or because I'm missing something?

Comment: Of course it is possible. Your browser can show the information. But the HTML content may change at any moment. It may be loaded using Javascript. If you want to get the data you need to simulate a browser because the data is just meant for a browser.